# Subtraction in ant

Tags: ant, properties, subtraction

I have two properties in Ant that both contain integers. I want to check if one is greater than the other. How can I accomplish that? Is there a way to use subtraction in ant? Then I could just subtract the two and check if the result is greater than 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use this sample:

```
<scriptdef name="intCompare" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="leftside"/>
    <attribute name="rightside"/>
    <attribute name="diff"/>
    <![CDATA[
   var leftSide = attributes.get("leftside");
   var rightSide = attributes.get("rightside");

   project.setProperty(attributes.get("diff"), leftSide-rightSide);
 ]]>

</scriptdef>

<target name="test">
    <intCompare leftside="555" rightside="9" diff="deviation"/>
    <echo message="The difference is: ${deviation}"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a groovy task

```
<taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

<groovy>
properties["greater"] = properties["x"] > properties["y"]
</groovy>
```